# How to save dart file in file system with android studio generated comments?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, comments, code-formatting

I like how **Android Studio** and **Visual Studio** , generate the comments for each closing brackets, but when I open the same file in **notepad++** or any other text editor, I don't see those comments. Is there a way to generate the saved dart file so it has those comments stored as part of the text code( in comment) ?

Here is one code example that how code looks in android studio.

[image: How It Looks in Android Studio]

but when opened with notepad it does not have the comment ***MaterialApp***. I am guessing there is some settings in android studio that will let me save file with generated comments, so it can be useful outside of Android studio like in git etc.

[image: Actual File contents]

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/code-style-dart.html and https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/formatting

Comment: These are really visual hints added by flutter/dart plugin. Even copy & paste doesn't work (even the HTML format in the clipboard doesn't contain these comments).

Comment: @simon-mourier what is the name of this plugin and does it have a git repo

Comment: I guess its in the flutter plugin (as dartfmt doesn't seem to be able to add these comments AFAIK), so I would be this but I'm unsure: https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij

Answer (score 1):

These comments are generated "on the fly" by the Flutter plugin for Android Studio. At no time, these comments are inserted into your source files. They are just shown within the IDE. So I think there is no way to "export" these comments.

Comment: what is the name of this plugin and does it have a git repo

Comment: You can find the source code here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij